# Can a SELECT statement return data and INSERT in to another SQL table at the same time?

Tags: sql-server

The below queries the Customer table reading the same data twice;

1. To insert selected fields in to a temp table for later use, and
2. To output data to the application calling it

Is there any variation of SQL SELECT statement that will achieve both objectives at the same time? (i.e. without reading the data twice?)

```xml
declare @CustomerID int = 1234
declare @IDsFromCustomer1 table (CustomerID int, TerritoryID int)

--IDs from Customer table
insert into @IDsFromCustomer1(CustomerID, TerritoryID)
    select CustomerID, TerritoryID
    from [Customer] 
    where [Customer].CustomerID = @CustomerID

--Return Customer table
    select [Customer].*
    from [Customer] 
    where [Customer].CustomerID = @CustomerID
```

Comment: Maybe an insert with an output clause?

Comment: I don't think output would work with insert since it's only inserting two column but needs to return all and `insert` can only ouput the inserted values - however it's a good suggestion as `merge` can accomplish this, I have added it as a suggestion in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three options.

The first is to select all required columns into the `@table variable` - do you *really* need `select *`? You can then return the data directly from `@IDsFromCustomer1`.

You would need to experiment with the effectiveness depending on the table width and logical reads in each case. Using `set statistics io on` will show you the logical reads, you can also see this in the properties of the execution plan in SSMS.

Your second option which may help would be to *not* use a table variable but declare an actual `#temp table`.

You could then return your data by selecting `from #IDsFromCustomer1` and joining back to your `Customer` table.

Using a temp table would have the benefit of SQL Server having statistics on the data and an optimal execution plan, plus you may benefit from a clustered index on the temp table also.

Testing to see which yields lower *logical reads* will (in most cases) highlight the best implementation.

A third option *might* work for you as mentioned by Dale in the comments, depending on your usage in when you want to have the temp table data available and when you want to output your results.

Using `merge` you can insert your data and also `output` data at the same time.

for example you could do the following

```
merge @IDsFromCustomer1 as t
using (
  select *
  from Customer
  where CustomerID = @CustomerID
) as s on 1=1
when not matched then
insert (CustomerID, TerritoryID) values (s.CustomerID, s.TerritoryID)
output s.*;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the OUTPUT clause of the INSERT statement

```
declare @CustomerID int = 1234
declare @IDsFromCustomer1 table (CustomerID int, TerritoryID int)

insert into @IDsFromCustomer1(CustomerID, TerritoryID)
output inserted.*
    select @CustomerID CustomerID,
           @CustomerID TerritoryID;

select * from @IDsFromCustomer1;
```

This script returns 2 identical query outputs.  First, one row is returned from the OUTPUT of the INSERT statement.  Second, all rows are returned from @IDsFromCustomer1.